# Rebuilding content access permissions

Tags: 6, users

I have a site with 760123 nodes, and 20123 users.

When visiting any page, I get the warning, "Rebuilding content access permissions." I tried rebuilding the access permissions, but the process is very slow.
I see [this post](http://drupal.org/node/399572), and tried the proposed solution, but it is not working.

I'm using  Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was conflict with xml sitemap module . i disable xml sitemap module

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're hitting your server's max_execution_time. It's quite likely with such a big number of nodes, and this operation taking a long time is normal.

Comment: no I increase max_execution_time and all of param in server. I think the problem is not related to the server

Answer (score 2):

Some of the modules will give you problems.
Ex : OG Access module , I disabled it and then rebuilt permissions.
Disable any access related modules(like TAC,node access etc) and then rebuild again.